# JSON formatting in iisnode

Tags: json, node.js, formatting, line-breaks, iisnode

When running my node.js application locally, I get nicely formatted JSON output with line breaks and spaces, like this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "asdf": "qwerty"
}
```

But when I run the same code in iisnode on Azure, I get this:

```
{"foo":"bar","asdf":"qwerty"}
```

Not that it makes any functional difference, and the latter one even saves some extra bytes, but it would be nice to know where the difference comes from.

Here is the code:

```
exports.test = function(req, res){
    var result = { foo : 'bar', asdf : 'qwerty'};
    res.send(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is likely with the `NODE_ENV` environment variable and `express`' [default configurations](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.1.0/lib/application.js#L85-L87):

```
app.defaultConfiguration = function(){
  // ...

  this.configure('development', function(){
    this.set('json spaces', 2);
  });

  // ...
};
```

Azure must have a different value for `NODE_ENV` (probably `'production'`) so the [`configure()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.configure) callback gets skipped.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the reason. I got the the 'development' settings in iisnode working by setting `node_env: development` in iisnode.yml.